# Data from server split into a listbox

Tags: c#, split

The data from server needs to be split into a `ListBox`. Below is my code.

```
private void button1_Click_2(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //String[] arr = new String[1];
            listBox1.Items.Clear();

            listBox1.Items.Add("No Of Items=" + _server.Q.NoOfItem.ToString());
            for (int i=0; i <= _server.Q.NoOfItem - 1; i++)
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add( _server.Q.ElementAtBuffer(i).ToString());               
            }

            listBox2.Items.Add("No Of Items=" + _server.Q.NoOfItem.ToString());
            for (int i = 0; i <= _server.Q.NoOfItem - 1; i++)
            {
                String words = _server.Q.ElementAtBuffer(i).ToString();               
                listBox2.Items.Add(words.Split(new char[] { '[' , ']', ' '}));                
            }
```

`listBox1` should show all the data retrieved from the server.  `listBox2` is supposed to show data that has been split.

How can this be done?

Comment: What is happening with your current code? and what output you want?

Comment: my output: name[asd] id[123] age[12]. it suppose to print.. asd in listbox1, 123 in listbox2, 12 in listbox3..but in my code i put all the result in listbox1 to do the checking. so, in listbox2 suppose print out asd

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
    private void button1_Click_2(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //String[] arr = new String[1];
        listBox1.Items.Clear();

        listBox1.Items.Add("No Of Items=" + _server.Q.NoOfItem.ToString());
        for (int i=0; i <= _server.Q.NoOfItem - 1; i++)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add( _server.Q.ElementAtBuffer(i).ToString());               
        }

        String words = _server.Q.ElementAtBuffer(i).ToString();  
        listBox2.Items.Add("No Of Items=" + _server.Q.NoOfItem.ToString());
        listBox2.Items.AddRange(words.Split(new char[] { '[' , ']', ' '}));           
    }
```

Comment: it still does not work..it appears as it does not do any split..but i try to put in message box. it does..only not in list box. but i really do need list box.please do help me

Comment: i try this code using a static data.. String words = "qwe rty dfg";  and it do work. but then when do split in server, it doesnt

Comment: Can you give me an example of what your data from the server looks like?  It will only get split if there are '[', ']' or/and ' ' characters in the string.

Answer (score 0):

```
    listBox1.Items.Clear();

    listBox1.Items.Add("No Of Items=" + _server.Q.NoOfItem.ToString());
    listBox2.Items.Add("No Of Items=" + _server.Q.NoOfItem.ToString());

    for (int i = 0; i <= _server.Q.NoOfItem - 1; i++)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(_server.Q.ElementAtBuffer(i).ToString());

        String words = _server.Q.ElementAtBuffer(i).ToString();
        string[] arr = words.Split(new char[] { '[', ']', ' ' });
        foreach (string word in arr)
            listBox2.Items.Add(word);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have your tried using Regex:

```
var pattern = @"\[(.*?)\]"; 
var matches = Regex.Matches(words, pattern);  
foreach (Match m in matches)
{  
   listBox2.Items.Add(/* Add matched item */);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
string[] strArray = words.Split(new char[] { '[' , ']', ' '})
for(int x = 0; x < strArray.Count; x++)
{listBox2.Items.Add(strArray[x]}
```

I guess you want to split words and add listboxs 2

Comment: i did use this before, but it wont work..when i try to put in message box..it does, just its not on the list box.

Comment: Might as well use AddRange(strArray).